# Apply type params to function (type level)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine I have the following function

```js
const wrap = <T>(t:T)=>({response:T})
```

Imagine I want to get the type of that function applied to some `T`

Let's say (with pseudo typescript syntax):

```js
type Wrapped<T> = ReturnType<typeof wrap<T>> //equivalent to {response:T}
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 4.7 introduced [instantiation expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#instantiation-expressions), which allow you to do this.

```
const wrap = <T>(t:T) => ({response: t})

type Wrapped<T> = ReturnType<typeof wrap<T>>
// type Wrapped<T> = {response: T}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcYF4YB4AqA+ACigC4cBKDPGAgbwQFMIVwJ7iYoBfMgKB6gCeKejADqyFMIAmuKpgBK9KAFcEYHEPpZBwkADN4E2Xh4B6UzEsA9APw8gA)